# Can black holes prevent heat death?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, black-holes, entropy, thought-experiment

I recently learnt that black holes possess [among the highest amounts of entropy in the universe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ab8JIzckx_M&list=PLsPUh22kYmNCHVpiXDJyAcRJ8gluQtOJR&index=4). I might have stretched the idea preposterously far, but is it possible  that this might be one of the reasons that could save the universe from heat death, or rather, at least prolong its onset, in a **hypothetical scenario**?

To elaborate the question, is possible to think (**within the constraints of present physics**) that all the increasing entropy of the universe go to the black holes, which then in its [radiations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation), release back photons and matter, which could again set in a new cycle of formation of astronomical objects, thereby saving us from a heat death.

Please note that I am not theorizing about anything, I am just interested to know about the workings of the present theories.

And please do consider my currently poor background on the mathematical aspects of what I have asked above.

Comment: how is the radiation from BH different than any other radiation, that you think this particular type of radiation could save us? Also is not heat death consequence of reaching maximal entropy? In that case it seems weird to me to try to save us from maximal entropy by trying to increase entropy as much as possible, by sending matter into BHs.

Comment: @Umaxo ,I guess I might have used the inaccurate definition of entropy  as the measure of "disorder" while thinking of the question .I am kind of inexperienced with these ideas, please do forgive my lack of understanding of the intricate details.

Comment: @Mann i think it would be better if you explained your reasoning more, rather than apologizing. That way it would be easier to either spot the mistake, or to see that you are indeed right. And btw i have no idea how the heat death or entropy of the whole universe works. I was just curious how did you arrive to your conclusions.

Comment: I didn't intend to arrive at conclusions, I just strung together a few concepts I recently read about in the manner of a thought experiment . .The major source of confusion for me was the Black Hole information paradox.

Comment: I replaced that title long ago.